# Error: Reference to undeclared resource. A managed resource "aws_backup_vault" "tct_vault" has not been declared in module.backup

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws

My current folder structure is as follows:

```
UNK
 ┣ BACKUP
 ┃ ┗ Terraform
 ┃ ┃ ┗ Modules
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ backup
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ main.tf
 ┗ BACKUP_VAULT
 ┃ ┗ Terraform
 ┃ ┃ ┗ Modules
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┗ backup_vault
 ┃ ┃ ┃ ┃ ┣ main.tf
main.tf
```

backup_plan has a dependency on backup_vault.

The main.tf in **backup** directory is as follows:

```
resource "aws_backup_plan" "tct_backup_plan" {
  name = "tct_backup_plan_001"
  rule {
    schedule = "cron(0 12 * * ? *)"
    rule_name = "tct_backup_plan_001"
    target_vault_name = aws_backup_vault.tct_vault.name
    lifecycle {
      delete_after = "2"
    }
  }
  advanced_backup_setting {
    resource_type = "EC2"
    backup_options = {
      WindowsVSS = "enabled" 
    } 
  }
}
```

The main.tf in the **backup_vault** directory is as follows:

```
resource "aws_backup_vault" "tct_vault" {
  name = "tct_vault_001"
}
```

The **root** main.tf is as follows:

```
module "backup" {
    source = "./UNK/BACKUP/Terraform/Modules/backup"
    depends_on = [
        module.backup_vault
    ]
}

module "backup_vault" {
    source = "./UNK/BACKUP_VAULT/Terraform/Modules/backup_vault"
}

provider "aws" {
  region = "us-east-1"
  access_key = "***"
  secret_key = "***"
}
```

After terraform init, on terraform plan I'm getting the following error:

```
 Error: Reference to undeclared resource
│
│   on UNK\BACKUP\Terraform\Modules\backup\main.tf line 6, in resource "aws_backup_plan" "tct_backup_plan":
│    6:     target_vault_name = aws_backup_vault.tct_vault.name
│
│ A managed resource "aws_backup_vault" "tct_vault" has not been declared in module.backup.
```

However, when I put the contents on main.tf of backup_vault inside the main.tf of backup, it is able to run without any errors.
When I have different modules in different path, it is not able to read from another module.

Is there any way to resolve this error with minimal changes and not introducing variables.tf?
Any help is immensely appreciated.

Comment: There are two modules? One in `backup` and one in `backup_vault`?

Comment: The short answer is no, there is no other way unless you define variables for the `backup` folder you can't pass anything to it.